# Проблема с matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Установил matplotlib. Строю простой график:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Если после этого вызвать `plt.show()`, то программа падает:

`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Версия python 3.9, версия matplotlib 3.4.3, среда разработки - PyCharm. В чём проблема?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000060510-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xC0000409-JavaFX-Application

Comment: проблема в Pycharm
попробуйте тот же код в Spyder или MS VS Code